# Set max_prepared_transactions in TestContainers PostgreSQLContainer

Tags: testcontainers

It's possible to set max_prepared_transactions in PostgreSQLContainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment i resolved by build new docker image of postgres, such as below:

`FROM postgres:10 
 RUN sed -ri "s!^#?(max_prepared_transactions)\s*=.*!\1 = 110!" 
 /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample`

[source](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/232#issuecomment-275259889)